# MVEL.eval(expression,Map<String,Object> args,Class<T> toType) equivalent in Groovy

Tags: groovy, mvel

I am currently using MVEL as an expression language in my code, as the base for a simple rule engine. Due to lack of support as well as relative obscurity, we are thinking of switching to Groovy as the expression language.

I use MVEL.eval(expression,Map args,Class toType) as the main evaluation method, which allows arbitrary arguments, without having to do any translation or interpretation.

Is there a similar method for Groovy ? Currently I was thinking something like (Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong)

My class

```
class GroovyRuleEvaluator implements RuleEvaluator {

private final GroovyShell shell;
private final Binding variableBinding;

public GroovyRuleEvaluator() {
 variableBinding = new Binding();
 shell = new GroovyShell(variableBinding);
}

@Override
public Object evaluateRule(String expression,Map<String,Object> args) {
 args.forEach((name,value) -> variableBinding.setProperty(name,value));
 return shell.evaluate(expression);
}

}
```

However, from what I understood from reading the documentation as well as [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/integrating.html), the Bindings for the shell are shared, and since I will be calling evaluateRule() multiple times for different expressions and arguments, it would cause errors, since the older bindings could be persisted.

Is there a correct way to remove the bindings once a rule is evaluated ?

Comment: create a new binding/shell in eval?

Comment: That is the final option, but I am not sure how expensive it will be to load the shell each time.

Comment: the GroovyShell ctor is rather thin: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.java#L89.  the expensive part is the eval.  also don't forget about security, if those strings can come from anybody.